Does ArcadeDB support indexing collections?
I am doing a hands-off evaluation of Graph Databases and came across ArcadeDB.
I scoured the documentation but did not find explicit mention of which of the supported types can also be indexed, I am especially interested in LIST collections.
I would appreciate any insight, perhaps I missed something in the manual.

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking which data types can be indexed. So AFAIK all data types are indexable, but only as a whole. So for scalar types (Boolean, Numbers, Strings, ...) this is as expected, and for collection types (Lists, Maps, ...) this means, for example, a list [1,2,3] is indexed as this specific list with these exact elements, and not as contents 1, 2, 3. However there are exceptions, such as the full-text index for strings, and BY KEY or BY VALUE modifiers for the first level of map types (objects), see https://docs.arcadedb.com/#SQL-Create-Index . For lists this is currently not possible, but there is an open feature request, see https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb/issues/1593 .

Exactly what I was looking for. Albeit the conclusion is disappointing it is not without a hint of hope. Thank you.
